# Entering the Winterhold College in Skyrim

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Im trying to enter the Winterhold College.
Feralda wants me to summon a Flame Atronach. It's not letting me do this spell. Help?

Answer (score 5):

From [UESP wiki, "First Lessons" quest article](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:First_Lessons):

> If you do not have the spell [Faralda] asks of you, she will offer to teach it to you for 30 gold.

Talk to Faralda and choose the appropriate conversation option to buy the '[Conjure Flame Atronach](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Conjure_Flame_Atronach)' spell. You should now  be able to use it.

Also, from the same UESP article linked above:

> Alternatively, you can attempt to [persuade](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Persuade#Persuade) her and avoid this test, or if you are here for the quest [Elder Knowledge](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Elder_Knowledge), you can tell her you are Dragonborn after which she will ask to see a [shout](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Dragon_Shouts). Either of these will get you in without needing to cast a spell. In order to persuade her, you will need a Speech skill of 100 (70 with the [Persuasion](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Persuasion) perk) or an [Amulet of Articulation](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Amulet_of_Articulation), available only by completing the Thieves Guild questline and becoming Guildmaster.

Comment: @JacobJones Glad to help. If this answer worked for you, you could set it as your accepted answer by clicking the 'check' icon below the voting buttons at the left side of this answer.