# How do I join the college of winterhold?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I have made it to the front area outside the college but I need to cast a fireball spell on this eye thingy and as I am a powerful Mage every time I cast the spell the elf lady gets hurt or if I am successful doing this without hurting her nothing happens.

Comment: Related: [Entering the Winterhold College in Skyrim](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/98085/4797)

Answer (score 7):

You need to cast the *Firebolt* spell, specifically, not just any fire spell. Otherwise, these are also possible spells to cast on the seal:

- Magelight
- Conjure Flame Atronach
- Fear

Or, cast Healing Hands on her. Your issue is most likely that you're casting *Fireball* instead of *Firebolt*, however.